# How to add react reference to HTMLCollection items?

Tags: reactjs, react-markdown

I'm trying to access attach references to each paragraph/heading in react-markdown. But I can't figure out how to add a ref to c below.

```js
const children = Array.from(div.children)
children?.forEach((c, i) => {
  // c = <p>...</p> or <h1>...</h1>
  // add ref from useRef to c
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone an element with `ReactcloneElement(element, propsObject, childrenAray)`. This preserves key and ref props from the cloned element. More info on that here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#clonelement

Alternatively you can do this:

```
const children = Array.from(div.children)
children?.forEach((c, i) => {
  return <c.type {...c.props} ref={yourRef} key={i}>{c.props.children}</c.type>
})
```